# How to restrict Front-End Editor on a page?

Tags: plugins, front-end

I am working on a site where the user can do everything from the front end. I am using the plugin from scribu called front-end editor. My problem, is that I have a dashboard page with all the options for the user and I do not want the user to be able to edit it. How do I restrict a page from being able to be edited by Front-End Editor. I have read the wiki on github for it here https://github.com/scribu/wp-front-end-editor/wiki/Actions-and-filters and can't find anything about restricting pages. Only categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GitHub-Wiki

### The `'front_end_editor_disable'`-filter

Use this filter if you want to completely disable the plugin for certain URLs.

Callback arguments:

`bool $disable`: The current state. Default: `false`

You can use conditional tags: *Conditionals tags return `bool true/false`, which means, if you want to disable it on a page, simply use `is_page()`, as it returns `true` for pages...*

Disable FEE on pages, as a (mu)plugin.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#73660) Disable Front Page Editor on pages */
function wpse73660_disable_on_author_pages( $disable )
{
    return is_author();
}
add_filter( 'front_end_editor_disable', 'wpse73660_disable_on_author_pages' );
```

Comment: Hi Kaiser, how would this look like then if I wanted to disable on a page titled "dashboard"?

Comment: @Ryan Have you read into [the Codex and Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)? There's `is_page()` and it takes an argument...